# JSF 2 selectOneRadio Dependend Validation

Tags: jsf-2, validation

i have a pretty simple jsf page with three selectOneRadio components. two of them within a panelGroup.

```
<t:selectOneRadio id="first" value="#{myBean.first}" required="true" requiredMessage="Please make a choice!">
<f:selectItem itemLabel="yeah" itemValue="true"/>
<f:selectItem itemLabel="no!" itemValue="false"/>
<f:ajax render="myform" execute="myform" />
</t:selectOneRadio>

<h:panelGroup rendered="#{not myBean.first}">
  <t:selectOneRadio id="second" value="#{myBean.second}" required="true" requiredMessage="Please make a choice!">
  <f:selectItem itemLabel="yeah" itemValue="true"/>
  <f:selectItem itemLabel="no!" itemValue="false"/>
  <f:ajax render="myform" execute="myform" />
  </t:selectOneRadio>


  <t:selectOneRadio id="third" value="#{myBean.third}" required="true" requiredMessage="Please make a choice!">
  <f:selectItem itemLabel="yeah" itemValue="true"/>
  <f:selectItem itemLabel="no!" itemValue="false"/>
  <f:ajax render="myform" execute="myform" />
  </t:selectOneRadio>
</h:panelGroup>
```

My problem is, that dependent on value of the first button, the panel should be shown or not. if it shows up, the two other radio selections shall be validated.

the current behaviour is that if i choose someting in  the first selectOneRadio, the required messages for the other two ones are displayed.

does anyone how to avoid that and validate two and three dependent on value one?

kind regards and thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

found the answer...sometimes i am blind :-)

setting the execute attribute to the current radio buttons solved it:

```
<t:selectOneRadio id="first" value="#{myBean.first}" required="true" requiredMessage="Please make a choice!">
<f:selectItem itemLabel="yeah" itemValue="true"/>
<f:selectItem itemLabel="no!" itemValue="false"/>

<f:ajax render="myform" execute="first" />

</t:selectOneRadio>
```

Comment: what about primefaces ? there are no attribute like `execute` in ajax